# Can I get Powershell to check if a system was restarted?

Tags: powershell, restart

I'm currently modifying some code, and below is what the current unmodified code is. For privacy reasons, actual file paths are replaced with "File Path".

```
Clear-Host
       $YN = Read-Host -Prompt "CONFIRM REBOOT [Y/N]"

       if(($YN -eq "Y") -or ($YN -eq "y"))
       {
           Get-ChildItem -Path "File Path" -Recurse -File | Move-Item -Destination "File Path\Archive" -Force

           $ScriptDir = Split-Path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
           $Log = New-Item "File Path\$(Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss) Restarts.txt" -ItemType File -Force
           $date = Get-Date -Format "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"

           Clear-Host
           Write-Host `n `n `n
           Write-Host "Rebooting all servers and verifying reboot status..." `n `n
           Write-Host "Please standby, process may take up to 30 minutes..." `n `n

           Restart-Computer -ComputerName $Servers -Wait -For PowerShell -Delay 2 -Force -Timeout 1800

           "----------------------------------Script executed on $date----------------------------------" + "`r`n" | Out-File $Log -Append

           foreach($computer in $Servers)
           {
               $PingRequest = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet
               if($PingRequest -eq $true)
               {
                   Add-Content -Path $Log -Value "$computer`: Reboot Successful." # Issue is here
               }
               else
               {
                   Add-Content -Path $Log -Value "$computer`: Please manually check server."
               }
           }

           Add-Content -Path $Log -Value "`n"
           Clear-Host
           Write-Host `n `n `n
           Write-Host "All done!" `n
           Write-Host "Please review logs, as script may have run into problems." `n `n
           Log-Location
           Pause
       }
       else
       {
           Clear-Host
           Write-Host `n `n `n
           Write-Host "Server Reboots Aborted." `n `n
           Pause
       }
```

My issue is the script as it currently stands, it simply does a ping request, which only confirms if the server is turned ON, not if it actually restarted. Is there a way for me to get PowerShell to check if the server has actually been restarted, or is this the best that PowerShell can do?

Comment: You can get the uptime through remote powershell and wmi.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the `.LastBootUpTime` from [`win32_operatingsystem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem) and then check that the value is greater than a previously stored date:

```
$now = [datetime]::Now
Restart-Computer -ComputerName $Servers -Wait -For PowerShell -Delay 2 -Force -Timeout 1800

foreach ($computer in $Servers) {
    $lastBoot = (Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computer -EA 0).LastBootUpTime
    if ($lastBoot -gt $now) {
        Add-Content -Path $Log -Value "$computer`: Reboot Successful."
    }
    else {
        Add-Content -Path $Log -Value "$computer`: Please manually check server."
    }
}
```